# Loop through Range, If Value = "x" Copy Value from Cell 8 Columns to the right to other Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a questionnaire-table where for each question (one question per row), an "x" can be set in Columns C through F, each of them indicating a different answer (C = worst, F = best). To the right of that table in Colum L through O are sentences, each according to the answers in the columns on the left.
If there is an "x" in one Cell, I want the according sentence from the right side to be copied to another Worksheet named "Textboxes", basically allowing me to create one worksheet with all the sentences from the answers of the questionnaire.

This whole table looks like this:   deleted image

The sentences on the right are 8 columns to the right to each answer on the left, meaning if the X is in column C (worst answer) the according sentence to be copied is 9 columns to the right, in column L. If the X is in column D, the sentence from the cell 9 columns to the right (column M) would be copied and so on.

I've written this code.

```
Option Explicit
Dim cell As range
Dim range As range
Dim Workbook As Worksheet

Sub Textboxes()

'New Worksheet
Sheets.Add
'Change Name
ActiveSheet.Name = "Textboxes"

Set range = Sheets("Questionnaire1").range("C11:F113") 'C11:F13 is the range where the answers/X's could be in 

For Each cell In range

    If cell.Value = "x" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Activate
        ActiveCell.Copy (Sheets("Textboxes").range("A1"))
    End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

The idea / desired behaviour is:

- loop through the table
- if Cell has an "x" move 9 cells to the right to find the desired sentence
- copy the sentence from that cell to the worksheet "Textboxes". (Ideally first sentence in A1, second in A2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"range" is VBA word so you can not use  it as variable. try to give some other name i.e range_1 instead of range.
and use the cell variable insted of activecell

```
cell.Offset(0, 9).Activate
```